# Kendo Angular 2 Grid Height

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I want my grid to have a dynamic height. Before with angular 1 and kendo i would do like this.

```
<kendo-grid id="grid" options="entityGrid.gridOptions"></kendo-grid>
```

With the following CSS:

```
#grid {
    height: calc(100% - 1em);
}
```

But with Kendo grid for angular2 when i try this it wont work.

```
<kendo-grid id="grid"
            [data]="entityGrid?.view | async"
            [scrollable]="'virtual'">
 </kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using scrolling (and static headers), the grid content area needs to have a height, too. Computing it dynamically based on the page is not supported at this time, and is not going to work with angular-universal. You can log this as a feature request on the [kendo-angular2 repo](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues), so that it is considered for implementation.

That said, you can use the following hack to make it work:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [
  `kendo-grid {
    height: calc(100% - 3em);
    margin-top: 3em;
  }
  kendo-grid .k-grid-content {
    height: calc(100% - 46px);
  }`
],
```

This will pass the styles in the component itself. The value `46px` is the size of the header, and `3em` is your desired offset.

See [this plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vT53ZXAhQgJkD0LHUn7X?p=preview) for a working demo.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to set dynamic height with following configuration

```
<kendo-grid class="grid"
   [kendoGridGroupBinding]="data"
   [ngStyle]="gridHeight"
</kendo-grid>
```

In TS file

```
public gridHeight = {
   height: 'calc(100vh - 140px)'
};
```

You can set height as per your requirement from TS